# terminfo disable XON/XOFF

Tags: shell, terminal, tty, stty, terminfo

I can disable XON/XOFF flow control:

```
stty -ixon
```

So I put this in my "~/.profile". However I have started making my own terminal
with "terminfo" and "tic", and I noticed these options:

```
xon_xoff          xon       xo     terminal uses xon/xoff handshaking

exit_xon_mode     rmxon     RX     turn off xon/xoff handshaking

xon_character     xonc      XN     XON character
```

Could I compile my terminal with some of these options and avoid having to put
the "stty" command in my startup file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short: no

long:

terminfo *describes* the features of a terminal.  Those particular capabilities likely were added to AT&T's list of possible terminal capabilities in the late 1980s to describe some long-forgotten terminal that didn't use `^S` and `^Q`.

curses in general ([ncurses specifically](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/TO-DO#L193)) doesn't pay any attention to these features (because no one uses them).  **`stty`** doesn't pay any attention for a different reason: it ignores the terminal database, being essentially a platform-dependent program with hard-coded knowledge to fill in the cases where a default initial value is needed.